# how to find which repo does one rpm package belong to

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

How to know which repo does one rpm package belong to?

I searched the yum manual, and I didn't find the option.
And it is useless to use `yum list installed`.

Comment: try `yum provides \`which ps\`` to find who provides ps

Comment: what i want to konw is how to get one specific rpm package's Repository

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `repoquery` command, for example.

```
repoquery -i nmap
```

Comment: yes, it works!
but it is to slow to query, speeding about 3~5s...

Comment: Glad it worked...

Comment: If plugins are not enabled by default use: ```repoquery --plugins -i nmap``` https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=578510