# subscription-manager + how to know which are the rpms that installed from the redhat repo

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, repository

after we subscribed to rhedhat repo by `subscription-manager`
and the we use yum install , in order to install some pkgs

in case of yum is needed some rpm's from the network , then yum will download all the required rom from network

so until now everything is clear

the question is - how to know which rpm's was download from the redhat repo?

I ask this question , because later I want to list all the rpm's that was download from redhat repo , and installed them on other machine without network ( yum install -  offline ) , in order to resolve all yum dependencies

Comment: Perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189442/117549 ?

Comment: how it can help me to know all rpm's that was installed from redhat repo?

Comment: So you’re asking us to help you violate your license agreement with Red Hat?

Comment: NO , I have license agreement and that fine , I dont ask this , what I asked is how to found all rpm's that are installed from the redhat repo

Comment: Do `rpm -qa --last` or `yum history`